# How to reuse layoutTemplate between routes?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Looking at devtools profiling, when I move between two routes with the same `layoutTemplate`, the layout's helpers are being rerun, and it looks like the HTML is being rerendered as well. How can I have iron router only render the yields and leave the layout alone?

EDIT code:

```
Router.map ->
  @route '/foo',
    layoutTemplate: 'headered'

  @route '/bar',
    layoutTemplate: 'headered'

Template.headered.helpers 
  test: ->
    console.log 'gets run when switching from /foo to /bar'

<template name="headered">
  {{test}}

  <header>
    {{getReactiveData}}
  </header>

  {{> yield}}
</template>
```

I don't want the `<header>` node to be rerendered. I don't want `getReactiveData` to be called when the route changes (only when the data changes).

Comment: added pseudocode. full app is at parlay.io, see eg going between index and `/new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something abnormal about my app, because IR doesn't normally rerender the layout between routes:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/qcu8QWASvPEjDEf5k/IR

Answer (score 1):

The code in `layoutTemplate` renders and the helpers and callbacks will always rerun because it needs to at least re-run the `{{> yield}}` that's nested inside it. Otherwise there's no point in using a `layoutTemplate`.

If you have code that should only run once I suggest breaking it out into another template that just sort of sits around and doesn't change as you go from path to path. `layoutTemplate` code reruns because it has to.

**edit** - The following might not work, but I think it should - **edit**

Another thing that you can try is put the code into `Template.layout.onCreated();` The template gets created once and can get re-rendered multiple times before you `destroy` it by navigating to a page that doesn't use that particular template.

**header template**

```
<template name="header">

</template>

Template.header.onRendered(function(){

});

Template.header.events({

});

Template.header.helpers({

});

<template name="layout">
  {{> header }}
  {{> yield }}
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you! I added the template code. By breaking it out into another template, do you mean like putting the `<header>` in a `{{> header_template}}`?

Comment: Although I have to wonder - what code do you have that can only run once and then stops running for all other routes?

Comment: Thanks, will try that out. I don't want the helpers to stop running – I want them to still be reactive. I just don't need them to rerun unnecessarily when the route changes, and I don't want the HTML rerendered. Like a todo app that always has the task count in the header, no matter what route you're on.